# validate-product.js being loaded twice

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, magento-2.0

I added the validate-product.js in my custom module. But when I refresh the page it's loading 2 instance of the validate-product.js. The first one is the js file from my custom module the second one is from `Magento_Catalog` I checked my theme directory but I don't have any content of that. I cleared my cache file and all but it's still loading the file in the Vendor Folder. I thought when I override it in my custom module it should not run the Vendor folder but it seems I'm wrong. Any idea on how to solve this?

Below is the content of my requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            addcartjs: 'Custom_Module/js/add_to_cart',
            canvasjs: 'Custom_Module/js/canvas_js_include',            
            productValidate: 'Custom_Module/js/validate-product',
        }
    }
};
```

Is this really how it works? if so how can I load my custom module validate-product.js file last so that the function in there will be the one to be used. But I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put a path in your **`requirejs`**, like below:

```
var config = {
   "map": {
       "*": {
           ...,
           "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product":"Custom_Module/js/validate-product",
           ...
       }
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the developer docs at all. This contains some examples on how to override core js.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html

Apologies if I have misunderstood